# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.<init>(boolean)'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I migrated my project to latest Spring cloud Hoxton.SR11:

***POM:***

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>Hoxton.SR11</version>
    </parent>    
     
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
        <artifactId>eureka-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.31.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependencies for Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End of dependencies for Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.0-M1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.20</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I get this error during startup:

```
    2021-05-21 15:33:28.848 DEBUG 32602 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : Application failed to start due to an exception

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.<init>(boolean)'
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$RepositoryAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.<init>(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:111) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.postProcess(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$getRepository$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.9.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:294) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1858) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1795) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:886) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:402) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1247) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1236) ~[spring-boot-2.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.engine.SkyshopEngineApplication.main(SkyshopEngineApplication.java:18) ~[classes!/:1.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[skyshop-engine-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[skyshop-engine-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[skyshop-engine-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[skyshop-engine-1.0.jar:1.0]

2021-05-21 15:33:28.853 ERROR 32602 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$RepositoryAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.<init>(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:111)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.<init>(boolean)'

The method's class, org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/opt/datalis/skyshop-engine-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-dao-1.2.9.jar!/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.class
    jar:file:/opt/datalis/skyshop-engine-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-tx-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource: jar:file:/opt/datalis/skyshop-engine-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-dao-1.2.9.jar!/
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource: jar:file:/opt/datalis/skyshop-engine-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-dao-1.2.9.jar!/


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue? Looks like I have a problem into my dependencies.

EDIT:

Out from `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< org.skyshop.engine:skyshop-engine >------------------
[INFO] Building skyshop-engine 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ skyshop-engine ---
[INFO] Verbose not supported since maven-dependency-plugin 3.0
[INFO] org.skyshop.engine:skyshop-engine:jar:1.0
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.993 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-21T19:32:13+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Looks like version conflict for spring-data-commons library, try to run this command and see if there are different versions of this library defined as dependencies ```mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons```

Comment: Hoxton is not compatible with boot 2.4.x, only boot 2.3

Comment: I have updated the post with mvn command output.

Comment: Can you advice how I can fix the issue, please?